# Why does Putty display garbage from COM port?

Tags: serial-port, putty

As shown in the screenshot below, I used Putty to display the phone number which has been sent by the a caller ID which is connected to COM port 5.

[image: Screenshot]

I expect Putty to display the phone number but instead of that it shows strange white line when the phone rings. I already configured both the COM5 and Putty to have same settings (Baud rate, Start/Stop bits...).

Has anyone got any idea why did putty behave like that? Thank you

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: @ Martin Prikryl .I am new here can you please tell me how to move it. Thank you.

Comment: Delete here, re-post there.